# How to hide default 'X' close button inside magnific popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I have used [Magnific-popup](https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html) in my jsp to display few messages to the user.

The code I have used to open magnific popup is as below:

```js
$.magnificPopup.open({
  items: {
    type: 'inline',
    src: '#idOfSomeDivInPage'
  },
  focus: '#someButtonId',
  closeOnBgClick: false,
  enableEscapeKey: false
}, 0);
```

Is there a way to `delete/hide` the 'X' button present on top right top corner of magnific popup by using jquery and css?

Comment: https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#options showCloseBtn "*Controls whether the close button will be displayed or not.*" - wasn't exactly hard to find.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `showCloseBtn` config as mentioned here in [doc](https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html).

**showCloseBtn**

> Controls whether the close button will be displayed or not.

```js
$.magnificPopup.open({
  items: {
    type: 'inline',
    src: '#idOfSomeDivInPage'
  },
  focus: '#someButtonId',
  closeOnBgClick: false,
  enableEscapeKey: false,
  showCloseBtn:false
}, 0);
```

Please check here with working [codepen](https://codepen.io/narendrajadhav/pen/zYYKmYy)

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround.

Please add following line in your code where you create your popup.

```
$('.mfp-close').css('display','none');
```

Hope this solution works.